# Facebook pixel not finding the products in the catalog

Tags: facebook, product, pixel, catalog

I am working with Facebook advertising campaigns and we recently move to a newer version of our Prestashop site and `Facebook pixel helper` shown that the product ID is not found in th catalog. [catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfAHB.png)

Data feed file for the catalog can be accessed by [link](https://www.incaltamintedame.ro/modules/facebookdynamicadsproductcatalog/feeds/catalog_1.xml). 
The product can be found in the Products section of the Facebook catalog online by that ID.

The pixel is associated as an event source for the catalog.

The Facebook help says that the content_id in the pixel should match the id field in the catalog feed and it does, then the catalog and the pixel should be connected as catalog-event source and they are. We contacted Facebook support and they gave us an idea regarding the ID field in the product catalog online, but that is not editable and the id field in the XML is automatically mapped to content_id in the catalog.

We think this is a permission issue because the pixel cannot search for the product in the catalog. What do you think?

Any help or lead is highly appreciable.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve>. For more information, please see How to Ask<https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> and take the tour<stackoverflow.com/tour>.

Comment: @CristianVirgilSimion Did you manage to solve the issue? Currently, I have the same situation.